# Map a table column with column of multiple tables using JPA

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

```
Table 1 : Booking

Columns : id (pk), date, **service_id**, etc

Table 2 : Wash_Service

Columns : id (pk), date, amount, wash_detergent etc

Table 2 : Dry_Service

Columns : id (pk), date, amount, dry_heat etc
```

I have the above 3 tables. The booking table keeps a record of all the booking in the website. The wash_service and dry_service table keeps a record of details pertaining to that service.

So, whenever a booking is made, I want the booking related info to be in the booking table, the service related info to be in the specific service table and both to be linked via the `service_id` column.

Any leads on how can I achieve it?

Comment: I *think* this is doable if the entity classes `WashService` and `DryService` inherit from the same base class, say `BaseService` with `@Inheritance(strategy=TABLE_PER_CLASS)` on the service-specific classes. The superclass probably needs to be annotated as `@MappedSuperclass`. Then the relation in `Booking` will be `@ManyToOne BaseService service`. *IF* this works, JPA will know to look at both tables for a matching entity. That will not be efficient; you may want to consider SINGLE_TABLE (like answer) or maybe different relations per service type and resolve in Java.

Comment: Thinking back, there may be a trick to be more efficient. Maybe have a `BaseBooking` class - again `@MappedSuperclass`; this has one subclass per service, so `WashServiceBooking`, `DryServiceBooking`, this time with `@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)` and a discriminator column. The base booking contains all the booking fields, except the relation to the specific service; the subclasses contain the relation. Maybe it is possible to map the FK to the same column for each subclass. This will probably run into problems if you want to fetch bookings and their services in 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put the services to a one table then the booking table could reference those services by their primary id. You can add another table/columns if you want to add details on the services.

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Service service;

    private Date date;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Service {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private String typeOfService;
}
```

Comment: This helps when the service table has less column. In my case each service table has almost 20 different fields.

Comment: I see, the design is a little bit problematic. I would suggest that you use Non-relational databases like MongoDB, etc. It's much more flexible than Relational databases